# Confused about this homework question on differentiation

Tags: derivatives

[image]

Given that $g'(x)=g(x)$ (graph of $g(x)$ is above), and $f(x+g(x))=x^3+x+1$, determine $f'(1)$.

I am confused because if $g'(x)=g(x)$, shouldn't $g(x)$ be $\exp(x)$? (Looking at $f(x+g(x))=x^3+x+1$, it seems it is not.)

Comment: Why does $f(x + g(x)) = x^3 + x + 1$ mean that $g(x) \neq e^x$?

Comment: Also, $g'(x)=g(x)$ gives $g(x)=ce^x$.

Comment: You can apply the chain rule. $f'(x + g(x))(1 + g'(x)) = 3x^2 + 1$ so with $x = 0$ we have $f'(0 + 1)(1 + 1) = 0 +1 = 1$. So $f'(1) = 1/2$.

Comment: Hint: The picture shows the initial condition must be $g(0) = 1.$ The differential equation is easy to solve and gives you an idea what to substitute for $x.$

Comment: @SeanRoberson $g(0) = 1$ right?

Comment: Caught it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly noticed:

$$y=e^x$$

In fact the image shows us the additional condizion $g(0)=1$. So we'll have:

$$f(x+e^x)=x^3+x+1$$

We differentiate both sides remembering the rule of the differentiation of a composite function. We call $h(x)=x+e^x$. So:

$$f(h(x))=x^3+x+1 \Rightarrow  f(h(x))h'(x)=3x^2+1 \Rightarrow f'(x+e^x)=\frac{3x^2+1}{e^x+1}$$

Now if $x=0$:

$$f'(1)=\frac{1}{2}$$

:)

Comment: @AndrewLi We clearly have $g(0)=1$ from the image.

Comment: whoops I missed that, you're right